# c# xml quitar espacios entre tags

Tags: c#, xml

buenas tardes, les hago una consulta, tengo un archivo xml en disco con una estructura determinada y con espacios entre tags, necesitaría eliminar dichos espacios y que todo los tags queden uno al lado del otro.

ejemplo

```
<Encabezado>
  <IdDoc>
    <TipoCFE>111</TipoCFE>
    <Serie>A</Serie>
    <Nro>11</Nro>
    <FchEmis>2020-06-09</FchEmis>
    <FmaPago>1</FmaPago>
    <InfoAdicionalDoc>Si Corresponde</InfoAdicionalDoc>
  </IdDoc>
  <Emisor>
    <RUCEmisor>123456789012</RUCEmisor>
    <RznSoc>Pablo Alonso</RznSoc>
    <NomComercial>Infofarma</NomComercial>
    <GiroEmis>TiendaPlaza</GiroEmis>
    <Telefono>12345678</Telefono>
    <CorreoEmisor>pepe@pepe.com.uy</CorreoEmisor>
    <EmiSucursal>Principal</EmiSucursal>
    <CdgDGISucur>4</CdgDGISucur>
    <DomFiscal>General Paz 1234 of 4</DomFiscal>
    <Ciudad>Montevideo</Ciudad>
    <Departamento>Montevideo</Departamento>
    <InfoAdicionalEmisor>Informacion adicional opcional</InfoAdicionalEmisor>
  </Emisor>
  <Receptor>
    <TipoDocRecep>2</TipoDocRecep>
    <CodPaisRecep>UY</CodPaisRecep>
    <DocRecep>219999830019</DocRecep>
    <RznSocRecep>MUNICIPIO LA PAZ</RznSocRecep>
    <DirRecep>AV. ARTIGAS ESQUINA RODO</DirRecep>
    <CiudadRecep>LA PAZ</CiudadRecep>
    <DeptoRecep>CANELONES</DeptoRecep>
    <PaisRecep>Uruguay</PaisRecep>
    <CP>11900</CP>
    <InfoAdicional>Informacion adicional</InfoAdicional>
    <LugarDestEnt>direccion de entrega de ser necesario</LugarDestEnt>
    <CompraID>1</CompraID>
  </Receptor>
  <Totales>
    <TpoMoneda>UYU</TpoMoneda>
    <MntTotal>193.8</MntTotal>
    <CantLinDet>1</CantLinDet>
    <MntPagar>193.8</MntPagar>
  </Totales>
</Encabezado>
```

Quiero que quede así:

```
<Encabezado><IdDoc><TipoCFE>111</TipoCFE><Serie>A</Serie><Nro>11</Nro><FchEmis>2020-06-09</FchEmis><FmaPago>1</FmaPago><InfoAdicionalDoc>Si Corresponde</InfoAdicionalDoc></IdDoc><Emisor><RUCEmisor>123456789012</RUCEmisor><RznSoc>Pablo Alonso</RznSoc><NomComercial>Infofarma</NomComercial><GiroEmis>TiendaPlaza</GiroEmis><Telefono>12345678</Telefono><CorreoEmisor>pepe@pepe.com.uy</CorreoEmisor><EmiSucursal>Principal</EmiSucursal><CdgDGISucur>4</CdgDGISucur><DomFiscal>General Paz 1234 of 4</DomFiscal><Ciudad>Montevideo</Ciudad><Departamento>Montevideo</Departamento><InfoAdicionalEmisor>Informacion adicional opcional</InfoAdicionalEmisor></Emisor><Receptor><TipoDocRecep>2</TipoDocRecep><CodPaisRecep>UY</CodPaisRecep><DocRecep>219999830019</DocRecep><RznSocRecep>MUNICIPIO LA PAZ</RznSocRecep><DirRecep>AV. ARTIGAS ESQUINA RODO</DirRecep><CiudadRecep>LA PAZ</CiudadRecep><DeptoRecep>CANELONES</DeptoRecep><PaisRecep>Uruguay</PaisRecep><CP>11900</CP><InfoAdicional>Informacion adicional</InfoAdicional><LugarDestEnt>direccion de entrega de ser necesario</LugarDestEnt><CompraID>1</CompraID></Receptor><Totales><TpoMoneda>UYU</TpoMoneda><MntTotal>193.8</MntTotal><CantLinDet>1</CantLinDet><MntPagar>193.8</MntPagar></Totales></Encabezado>
```

Les agradezco enormemente si me pueden dar una mano con esto

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo más simple que podrías hacer es leer todo el archivo, quitar los saltos de línea y volverlo a guardar.

```cs
string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(path);
xmlString = xmlString.Replace("\n", "");
File.WriteAllText(path, xmlString);
```

Si te quedan espacios y los quieres remover

```
<tagA>  <tagB>Contenido</tagB> <tagC>   </tagC> </tagA>
```

Podrías construir un algoritmo que analice el contenido entre `>` y `<` y si solo son espacios en blanco, los sustituya por `string.Empty` alguno como el siguiente:

```cs
public static string XMLRemoveEspacios(string xmlString, bool permitirInformacionVacia)
{
   string xmlFinal = string.Empty;
   string contenido = string.Empty;
   bool esContenido = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < xmlString.Length - 1; i++)
   {
      char caracter = xmlString[i];
      if (esContenido)
      {
         bool finContenido = caracter == '<';
         if(finContenido)
         {
            bool esInformacion = xmlString[i + 1] == '/';
             xmlFinal += 
                     ( permitirInformacionVacia && esInformacion ) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contenido) ?
                     contenido : string.Empty;
            xmlFinal += caracter;
            esContenido = false;
            contenido = string.Empty;
         }
         else
         {
            contenido += caracter;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         xmlFinal += caracter;
         esContenido = caracter == '>';
      }
   }

   return xmlFinal;
}
```

El resultado sería el siguiente si no se permite informacion vacía:

```
<tagA><tagB>Contenido</tagB><tagC></tagC></tagA>
```

y si sí se permite, sería el siguiente:

```
<tagA><tagB>Contenido</tagB><tagC>   </tagC> </tagA>
```

Answer (score 0):

El proceso que quieres hacer se denomina *XML Canonicalization* y tal vez se pueda traducir como *Canonizar el XML* - aunque la canonizacion nos la merecemos los programadores :-) - y suele usarse para firmar digitalmente documentos XML.

Hay una clase en .NET llamada `XmlDsigC14NTransform` que hace el trabajo. Aqui te paso un ejemplo tomado de esta otra respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/3390769/2371714 y simplemente canoniza el archivo sign.xml y lo guarda en child1.xml

```
string path = @"sign.xml";
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    xDoc.Load(fs);
}

// canon node list
XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/*");

var transform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform(true)
                    {
                        Algorithm = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl
                    };

var validInTypes = transform.InputTypes;
var inputType = nodeList.GetType();
if (!validInTypes.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(inputType)))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Input");
}

transform.LoadInput(xDoc);
var innerTransform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();

innerTransform.LoadInnerXml(xDoc.SelectNodes("//."));
var ms = (MemoryStream) transform.GetOutput(typeof (Stream));
ms.Flush();
File.WriteAllBytes(@"child1.xml", ms.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué .NET API para XML utilizas? Supongo que es suficiente utilizar `PreserveWhitespace = false`, por ejemplo,

```
var doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.PreserveWhitespace = false; 
doc.Load("archivo-original.xml"); 
doc.Save("archivo-sin-espacios.xml");
```

si utilizas `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.